# Unable to get result for dot product C programing

Tags: c

If I print result inside my function, I get the correct answer but if I print the result in `main`, I get 1. What am I doing wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int dotpro(int v1[], int v2[], int result, int n);

int main(void) {
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int v1[n], v2[n], result;

    printf("Enter arr1: ");
    for(i= 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
    printf("Enter arr2: ");
    for(i= 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &v2[i]);

    dotpro(v1, v2, result, n);

    // enter code here
}

int dotpro(int v1[], int v2[], int result, int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += (v1[i] * v2[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", result);
}
```

Comment: please show us the printing of the result in `main()`;
btw: the function dotpro should return a value but does not.
What does "enter code here" mean?

Comment: Hint: Either return the result value as return value of the function `dotpro` - 
Or you can return the result value as reference value `result`, but then you have to declare a pointer as `int dotpro(int v1[], int v2[], int *result, int n)` and use `*result` instead of `result` in the function (also check if the pointer is not NULL). When calling `dotpro` you have to call the address of result in the main like:
`dotpro(v1, v2, &result, n);`

Comment: Nick, With `int  result; ...  dotpro(v1, v2, result, n);`, what value do you think `result` has when the function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to return the result and are attempting to pass the `result` parameter by value instead of by pointer reference.

Instead of this:

```
int dotpro(int v1[], int v2[], int result, int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += (v1[i] * v2[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", result);
}
```

Do this:

```
int dotpro(int v1[], int v2[], int n) {
    int i;
    int result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += (v1[i] * v2[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And adjust the declaration at the top of the file to match:

```
int dotpro(int v1[], int v2[], int n);
```

Then in main, invoke as follows:

```
result = dotpro(v1, v2, n);
printf("result = %d\n", result);
```

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow Nick. If you found the answer useful, please upvote the answer and/or accept it.